# cassandra internode encryption replication is working fine even though the global.truststore file is removed from one of the node in cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have deployed 4 node cassandra cluster in two regions each.

Region 1 : 
Node 1
Node 2

Region 2 : 
Node 3
Node 4

i have created and imported the keystore files and updated in encyrption options

node2.cer  node2.keystore global.truststore.

I have removed the global.truststore file in node2 in region 1, and inserted one record in node2, which should not replicate the inserted records to other nodes, since the SSL encryption will not work due to global.truststore file is removed.

Observation : 
After insert in node 2 ,
No replication for the inserted node in node 3 and node 4.
but node 1 has that inserted record.

Note : I have set internode encryption option as "all", any help from experts to undertstand, why node 1 is having the replication of inserted records, even though node 2 does not have global truststore value.

Comment: When you removed the truststore, did you bounce the node?